# Statick Block wysiwyg Image Uploader Button is not shown in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, jquery

This is the Image with Problem in which I did not see "image upload" and "Delete" button [image]

Our Magento See this button like below image
The Magento Actual Output
[image]

**So how can i display this button**

Console Shows Error like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
    at Object.Flex.getFlashPlayerVersion (flex.js:164)
    at Object.Flex.checkFlashPlayerVersion (flex.js:46)
    at klass.detectFlashVersion (flex.js:425)
    at klass.initialize (flex.js:200)
    at new klass (prototype.js:101)
    at klass.initialize (flexuploader.js:63)
    at klass (prototype.js:101)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (prototype.js:612), <anonymous>:6:56)
    at prototype.js:612
    at prototype.js:865
```

Comment: try to open in different browser, try to open in chrome

Comment: I try this already but not shown can you tell me from where this button comes? or some hints if you know

Comment: button is coming from `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/`
can you check permission for directory and file `skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/`

Comment: actually this is a static block problem so is it come from media file?

Comment: what permission i need. 755 permission is already given

Comment: 755 permission is okay , you just need to check this button html is come or not , may be your 3rd party magento theme has been override some file

Comment: i update my question i found some flex.js error in console and i put original magento flex files now but still that error comes

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, it was browser related. In Chrome: Settings - Advanced Settings - Content Settings - Flash - turn off 'Ask First'.

Comment: or put it in the "allowed" list. ModPagespeed was also causing a issue for me even with ModPagespeedDisallow "*/index.php/admin*"

Comment: no longer an option in chrome, you have to fallback on firefox

Answer (score 1):

It's cause browser disabling flash last time. You can try to use some existing solution, like [enter link description here](https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader)
Or upgrade magento to latest version, they already fixed it there

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed an admin theme? The styling looks different, maybe that theme is conflicting or has bugs?

Try removing the admin theme and see if the problem persists.

Comment: yes i disable my theme and still there is a problem there is a flex jquery  missing problem